# How to access cassandra 2.0.3 from hive 0.9.0

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-jdbc

I have installed cassandra 2.0.3 and hive 0.9.0.

I have followed the below link for hive support for cassandra.
https://github.com/milliondreams/hive

But it says "Cassandra Hive handler working with Cassandra 1.2.6 and hive 0.9" and my cassandra version is 2.0.3

Could any one guide me on how to access cassandra 2.0.3 from hive 0.9.0 in detail as I am new to cassandra and hive.

--
Harry

Comment: Have you tried that hive handler? I will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

This Hive handler should also work for Cassandra 2.0, as it is using CQL3.

Answer (score 0):

I have tryed it with shark, not Hive. And then found out that it dose not work for cassandra 2.0x, because spark use hadoop2 and cassandra 1.26 use hadoop. It could map the table between shark and cassandra, but can not read data when through a spark process(require cassandra all 2.0x).

the error is java.lang.InstantiationError: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.

I have created a project from my work, for cassandra 2.0.4, hive 0.11 and hadoop 2.0

try it

https://github.com/2013Commons/hive-cassandra